# Lift CRUD "list all" problem

Tags: scala, crud, lift

I'm trying to follow [this](http://neuralmonkey.blogspot.com/2009/08/lift-listing-entities-without-crudify.html) tutorial. I've got a non empty db. But the table does not get propagated. I tried debugging it: correct records are returned by the `toShow` method, on each iteration of the `flatMap` it has a correct, non-empty instance of the item, but the result, this method returns is this: `List(\n{16 spaces here},\n{16 spaces here})`. And the table does not get propagated.
My updated code is as follows:

ListCar snippet:

```
class ListCar {

  def list(xhtml: NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = {
    toShow.flatMap(car =>
      bind("car", xhtml,
        "name" -> car.name.is,
        "owner" -> car.owner.name
      )
    )
  }

  private def toShow = {
    Car.findAll();
  }

}
```

list.xhtml:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Owner</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <lift:list_car.list>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <car:name/>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <car:owner/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </lift:list_car.list>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: What if write '"name" -> car.name' instead of '"name" -> car.name.is' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this one by editing the html file:
instead of wrapping `<tr>` in `<lift:list_car.list>`, I changed it to `<tr class="lift:listCar.list">`, and it worked.

Comment: Please note that this works because you are using HTML5 format in your html files.  The `<lift:list_car.list>` syntax only works when you use the XHTML format.

Answer (score 0):

See example here (in the very bottom): http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/View_First . Unfortunately I can't try code right now. You may try two more options:

1. replace `"name" -> car.name.is` with `"name" --> car.name` (`-->` instead of `->`)
2. replace `"name" -> car.name.is` with something like `"name" -> SHtml.text(car.name.is)`

Comment: Both approaches did not work. But I've found the one, that worked (my answer to this question).